# F# interactive:how to display/change current working directory

Tags: f#

in F# interactive:how to display/change current working directory?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
> open System;;

> Environment.CurrentDirectory;;
val it : string = "C:\\"
> Environment.CurrentDirectory <- @"c:\temp";;
val it : unit = ()
> Environment.CurrentDirectory;;
val it : string = "c:\\temp"
```