# F# FSI, Change working directory

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have the following file located in a "New Folder" of Desktop:

```
// File location: "C:\Users\my_user_name\Desktop\New folder\AddOne.fs"
// 
module internal AddOneModule

let AddOneFunction x = x + 1
```

I can access this file by using #load on the full path name using FSI F# Interactive.

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 4.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> #load "C:\Users\my_user_name\Desktop\New folder\AddOne.fs";;
//[Loading C:\Users\my_user_name\Desktop\New folder\AddOne.fs]
//namespace FSI_0002
//  val AddOneFunction : x:int -> int

> open AddOneModule;;
> AddOneFunction 100;;
//  val it : int = 101
```

How do I change the working directory so that I can access the file using relative path?

[F# interactive:how to display/change current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411526/f-interactivehow-to-display-change-current-working-directory)

I tried something similar to the post above, but FSI still tries to find the file in the Temp folder:

(RESET FSI)

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 4.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> open System;;
> Environment.CurrentDirectory <- @"C:\Users\my_user_name\Desktop\New folder";;
//val it : unit = ()

> #load "AddOne.fs";;

//  #load "AddOne.fs";;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

//C:\Users\my_user_name\Desktop\New folder\stdin(3,1): error FS0078: Unable to find 
//the file 'AddOne.fs' in any of
// C:\Users\my_user_name\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: My recommendation is never to type into FSI directly. Create a script file and send lines of code to FSI as you need. This way you you can `#load` files from relative paths, you get full tooling support (autocompletion, error underlining) and you never have to type `;;`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of changing the working directory you may achieve the desired using a trick with [`__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` built-in identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/source-line-file-path-identifiers).

To begin with, you need a certain anchor point in directory structure. For illustration purposes let's assume you are on Windows and let this anchor point be your user directory, which is defined by `%USERPROFILE%` environment variable. Place there a script `anchorfsi.fsx` containing the following single line of code:

`#I __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__`

That's basically all you need to do. Now, regardless from what location you shoot your `fsi` using command line `fsi --load:%USERPROFILE%\anchorfsi.fsx`, you can use relative paths in your scripts and in interactive commands.

Turning to the setup in your question with loading `.\desktop\new folder\addone.fs`, the following screenshot demonstrates achieving the desired:

[image: demo]

Notice how the entered relative path `".\desktop\new folder\addone.fs"` was correctly mapped to the absolute one `C:\Users\gene\desktop\new folder\addone.fs` *without any dependency* upon the `fsi` working directory whatsoever.