# Use environment variables in F# directives

Tags: f#

In FSI, is it possible to run something like

```
#I @"%APPDATA%/npm/node_modules/blabla/bin/"
```

instead of

```
#I @"C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/blabla/bin/"
```

Any other options to make it not sensitive to username?

Comment: Install your packages locally instead of to `%APPDATA%`?

Comment: Nah, lots of other stuff depends on it being installed globally

Comment: Can you extract and combine the Path programatically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709269/difference-between-specialfolder-localapplicationdata-and-specialfolder-appli

Answer (score 1):

Not likely you can use environment variables in `#I` FSI directives.

However you may make your package installation agnostic of user name by using the trick with [`__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` built-in identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/source-line-file-path-identifiers) similar to one I've described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46322887/917053):

- create a file `anchorfsi.fsx` with the single line of code

  ```
  #I __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
  ```

  and put it into the directory %APPDATA% points to
- add to the command line starting your FSI the term

  ```
  --load:%APPDATA%\anchorfsi.fsx
  ```

Now you can use relative paths in your `#r` directives.

Just for illustration I put into directory associated with my user profile a folder `testlib` containing `FSharp.Data.dll`. The snip below shows how it gets referenced from FSI using the outlined above technique:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can I trick VS Code in a similar way?

Comment: Do not use VS Code so dunno, but VS 2017 can be tricked in quite a similar manner. Let me know if you'd be interested and I'll update my answer with specifics.